# send and receive mail from localhost to localhost in jsp

Tags: jsp, smtp, localhost, tomcat7, jakarta-mail

Hey everyone,
             I've tried to much. also in googling but not succeed what i've to make is one mail system in which user can register in that with a new email id. and after that there should be mail box by which user can send and receive mail but only who have my mail server's account... i designed all the stuff like sign up , login, mail inbox, compose mail, and at the end i've tried with my localhost port no 25 but it's refusing connection. i've tried smtp.gmail.com then it's work fine but when i change it to my localhost port 25 then it's not working... is there any another changes thet i've to do there??? give me some suggestion. i am using Eclipse with Tomcat7

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you have a SMTP agent running on your system and listening on port 25 (the default). On Linux/BSD/etc. a good one is [Postfix](http://www.postfix.org/), while on Windows the simplest option is [IIS SMTP server](https://www.microsoft.com/technet/prodtechnol/WindowsServer2003/Library/IIS/e4cf06f5-9a36-474b-ba78-3f287a2b88f2.mspx?mfr=true)

Comment: oh... it's not installed on my system... Thanks!